# FCM iOS Push Notifications not working in background under ADHOC release

Tags: ios, firebase, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to implement push notifications in iOS using FCM. The issue is that when I generate an ADHoc build I am not able to receive the Push Notifications when app is in background, instead I get all the notifications on the consequent app start.

Under the debug build it works fine.

I have uploaded the certificates in Firebase Console and done necessary installation steps as mentioned in official guide at firebase.

The AppDelegate methods that I am using are directly from the quickstart-iOS git of firebase.

I have tried switching from sandbox to prod after turning off method swizzling. But it is not working.

I am using swift3 Xcode8 for development